# Use string as filter in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to use a string variable as the filter argument in dplyr?  For example:

```
filter(iris,Sepal.Length > 6)
```

would be replaced with

```
string <- 'Sepal.Length > 6'
filter(iris,string)
```

Basically, I am looking for the entire filter string to be a variable as I am creating the filter string pragmatically.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: you might consider changing the accepted answer because the current one is deprecated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to filter with a string argument, you'll need to use `filter_()` instead of `filter()`

```
string <- 'Sepal.Length > 6'
filter_(iris, string)
```

Also note that it's recommended to use the `*_()` functions when programming.

Comment: what would the new tidyeval version of this now be?

Comment: This is now deprecated :(

Comment: @ashleych I posted an up-to-date answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only way I have found that works in the new tidyval:

```
> s = "A<3"
> data.frame(A=1:10, B=1:10) %>% filter(eval(str2expression(s)))
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

However, I have not figured out [how to do this with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208791/apply-a-vector-of-filters-based-on-a-string-or-vector-of-strings-in-dplyr/59208855).