# tidyeval way to programatically send values to filter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Picking up on an earlier thread, ([Use string as filter in dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554225/use-string-as-filter-in-dplyr?answertab=active#tab-top)),
what would the new [tidyeval](/questions/tagged/tidyeval) answer for this be, as `filter_` is being deprecated.

Is there a way to use a string variable as the filter argument in [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)? For example:

```
filter(iris,Sepal.Length > 6)
```

would be replaced with

```
string <- 'Sepal.Length > 6'
filter(iris,string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
filter(iris, !! rlang::parse_expr(string))
```

But as far as I understand the tidyeval philosophy, code as string is frowned upon and there shouldn't be `string <- 'Sepal.Length > 6'` in the first place.

Maybe instead:

```
condition <- expr(Sepal.Length > 6)
filter(iris, !! condition)
```

Comment: expr is exactly what I was looking for !