# Apply a vector of filters based on a string (or vector of strings) in dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

R and the tidyverse have some extremely powerful but equally mysterious methods for turning strings into actionable expressions. I feel like one needs to be an expert to really understand how to use them.

**NOTE:** this question differs from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803104/how-to-pass-an-expression-in-a-string-to-a-verb-in-dplyr-0-7-2) in that I specifically ask about a vector (that is multiple) filter conditions. I demonstrate a solution for single filters that fails when I try multiple ways of extending it to multiple filters.

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
df = data.frame(A=1:10, B=1:10)
df %>% filter(A<3, B<5)
```

But where the filters are contained in either a string such as `"A<3, B<5"` or a character vector such as `c("A<3", "B<5")`.

I can do

```r
df %>% filter(eval(str2expression("A<3")))
#   A B
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
```

But this does not work:

```r
df %>% filter(eval(str2expression("A<3, B<5")))
Error in str2expression("A<3, B<5") : <text>:1:4: unexpected ','
1: A<3,
       ^
```

These don't work either:

```r
> df %>% filter(!!c(str2expression("A<3"), str2expression("B<5")))
Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
> df %>% filter(!!!c(str2expression("A<3"), str2expression("B<5")))
Error: Can't splice an object of type `expression` because it is not a vector
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Evaluating a vector of expressions from `str2expression` for some reason only applies the last expression:

```r
> df %>% filter(eval(c(str2expression("A<3"), str2expression("B<5"))))
#   A B
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 4 4 4
```

Using a vector of evaluated expressions fails altogether:

```r
> df %>% filter(!!!c(eval(str2expression("A<3")), eval(str2expression("B<5"))))
Error in eval(str2expression("A<3")) : object 'A' not found
```

I can do:

```r
> df %>% filter(!!!c(expr(A<3), expr(B<5)))
#   A B
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
```

and this tells me that `expr(A<3)` is NOT the same thing as `str2expression("A<3")`

But that isn't starting from strings.

What to do?

Comment: I have flagged my question to reopening because my question _specifically_ asks about a vector of conditions. The "similar" question does not. The answers are different. Furthermore, my answer is simpler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803104/how-to-pass-an-expression-in-a-string-to-a-verb-in-dplyr-0-7-2

Comment: In the post I linked, there is `parse_exprs` `select_expr <- rlang::parse_exprs( select_str )` which is the same as the other answer in this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learning from @Ronak Shah's answer, apparently, in dplyr I can use multiple conditions with a single `&` in filter instead of a comma. I don't understand this at all---it is not the same thing as an *and* logical:

```
> df %>% filter(A<3 & B<5)
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
> df %>% filter(A<3 && B<5)
    A  B
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
```

Nevertheless, the following does work:

```
> df %>% filter(eval(str2expression("A<3 & B<5")))
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
> df %>% filter(eval(str2expression("A<6 & B<5")))
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

Comment: `&` and `&&` are not the same. Read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and

Answer (score 4):

You could use `parse_exprs` from `rlang`

```
library(dplyr)
expr <- c("A<3", "B<5")

filter(df, !!!rlang::parse_exprs(expr))

#  A B
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
```

---

Or you could combine the two expressions and then use it in `eval`

```
filter(df, eval(parse(text = paste0(expr, collapse = "&"))))

#  A B
#1 1 1
#2 2 2
```